# How do I access s3 bucket from IAM account using Java

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an s3 account with `AmazonS3FullAccess` put when I try to use it to run `s3.listObjects("name")` I get a 403 error...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>59C510407179770D</RequestId><HostId>aLPzqYkTKx6nkUWVtZWYS+2fYexzniKWkn2D9+aG6pdxBAjtxAcC85uvGC4HqDnQIifLaf+oy1E=</HostId></Error>
```

`s3.doesBucketExistV2("name")` returns true.

My policy looks like this...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to add the user somewhere?

**Update**

Looks like it could be a problem with not getting the AWS creds (which is weird becuase of this line)...

> Deprecated. By doesBucketExistV2(String) which will correctly throw an exception when credentials are invalid instead of returning true. See Issue #1256.

If I run `((AmazonS3Client) s3).awsCredentialsProvider.getCredentials()` it returns null. My creds are in a amazon.properties file like this...

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:amazon.properties")
})
// amazon.properties
amazon.accessKey=${AMZN_ACCESS_KEY}
amazon.secretKey=${AMZN_SECRET_KEY}
aws.accessKeyId=${AMZN_ACCESS_KEY}
aws.secretKey=${AMZN_SECRET_KEY}
```

and `echo $AMZN_ACCESS_KEY` returns the value I would expect.

**Update 2**

It appears to be something with the properties not getting read properly if I am explicit like this...

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(service.getRegion())
            .build();
```

It worked, so 2 questions 1.) Why does the `doesBucketExistV2` return true even when I am not logged in properly 2.) Why are the system properties not working?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass bucket name as below. The sample code should be as below

Refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property).

```
/* The following example list two objects in a bucket. */

 var params = {
  Bucket: "name", 
  MaxKeys: 2
 };
 s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
```

Comment: Not correct according to javadocs... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-